# Moon vs Sun size and distance 400 times

Tags: earth, sun, moon, distance

I have seen below statement, and it doesn't sound right:

> The Sun and Moon seem to have the same size because of this amazing coincidence:
>   the moon is 400 times smaller than the Sun and 400 closer than the Sun.

Checking 400 from [this source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solar/moonscale.html):

The Moon's distance from the Earth: 384,000 km and diameter: 3,480 km
The Sun's distance from the Earth: 149,000,000 km and diameter of 1,392,000 km

*Distance*: 149,000,000 / 384,000 = 388.02, OK almost 400
*Size*: 1,392,000 / 3,480 = 400 spot on.

Does being X times further make it look X times smaller?

I have seen this post but not sure it answer my question:
[Can the apparent equal size of sun and moon be explained or is this a coincidence?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24912)

***Note:*** First time post, let me know if the post is suitable.

Comment: The link you provide seems a duplicate  of your question, imo

Comment: Ah, the silent downvoters...

Comment: Yes the apparent equal size can be "explained" (as in the answer), and Yes, it is a coincidence. The earth's moon is HUGE relative to the size of the earth, compared with the moons of every other planet in our solar system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Also called the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem).